# Side Effects of Zend-Servicemanager-di after Removal?

Tags: zend-framework3

To whom it may concern:
I am going to install simpavl/zf3-shoppingcart, installation failed on account of zend-servicemanager-di that should be removed.
Does the removal of this component has some sort of side effects?
I never used its library directly in my site, but if servicemanager component uses its features implicitly, I believe I can not remove it.
Kian William

Answer (score 0):

I removed it, so far no side effects and my site works fine
Kian William